# Excel formula to average selected cells based on certain criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003, formulas

I am using Excel 2003.
I have a table:

Date -   Column X -   Column Y -   Column Z - Age

I want to find the AVERAGE for the numbers in the Age Column where the Date in the Date colum = cell A1
There are hundreds of records - I have tried using INDEX and MATCH but cant get it to work. I only end up with the first matching record.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Tom

Comment: Is the layout of your table irrelevant? As in: you just need the data? If so you could do the following: put this in F2 =IF(A2=$A$1,E2,0) Autofill to the last row and then put =Average(F1:F<lastrowhere>). You'll have to fill in F1 manually.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(X:X=A1,Z:Z))
```

with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Hi Pnuts, I am using =AVERAGE(IF(E:E=L1,I:I)) where E is the column with the dates in, L1 has todays date and I is the numbers that I want to average. I am getting a #NUM! error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Tom:

I'm not sure if Excel 2003 has AVERAGEIF(), but if it does, use that. You designate your criteria range, criteria, and average range, and it does the rest.

If Excel 2003 does NOT have AVERAGEIF(), then you could use SUMIF() to get the sum of Ages on a certain date and then divide that by a COUNTIF() that counts the ages that occur on your date.

Hope that helps,
Matt via www.ExcelArchitect.com

Comment: Tom, I just thought of a follow-up if for some reason Excel 2003 doesn't even have SUMIF or COUNTIF. Add another two columns to the right of your data. In every cell of the first column, add an if statement to pull the age from the row if it meets the date criteria. In the second column, instead of pulling the age, just write 1 in the cell. Sum both cells at the bottom of your worksheet. You now have a home-made version of SUMIF (first column) and COUNTIF (second column). Just divide the total from the first column by the total from the second column to get your average age on the date.